# Переменные среды java в Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в Ubuntu задать переменную среду (добавить директорию установки java), чтобы при запуске консоли не нужно было указывать путь к компилятору и интерпретатору java?

Например, у меня java в папке "homejava".

Comment: странно что у вас вообще возникла така необходимость, ставил jdk через "центр ПО", ничего ручками не прописывал.

***:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_23"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11pre) (6b23~pre10-0ubuntu5)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: Да  он наверное ручками ставил.

Comment: на работе отсутствует интернет, приходится скачивать дома и приносить на работу файлы, да ставил в ручную по инструкциям на сайте(через командную строку), а есть методы сделать это проще?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например в /home/<user>/.bashrc добавить:

```
export JAVA_HOME='/home/<user>/homejava'
PATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

После чего перезагрузиться или просто запустить .bashrc

Comment: Достаточно просто загрузить новый зкземпляр bash.

Comment: А можно еще проще (если не нужно особая переменная JAVA_HOME)

PATH='/home/<user>/homejava':$PATH

Добавление текущей директории в PATH - дурной тон, способный нарушить безопасность.

Comment: Это удобно. В случае рабочей машины для разработки вряд ли пострадает безопасность.

Comment: Да,только незнакомому человеку на форуме так не советуйте. А то он в другой раз сделает такое на другой машине... Надо сразу привыкать к безопасному администрированию

Comment: после закрытия консоли опять не работает, нужно наново вводить, а нету метода чтобы раз и навсегда?

Comment: Так Вам же написали: в файл .bashrc, который лежит в Вашей домашней папке, сделать в конце добавление. И будет работать всегда.

Comment: Заработало, спасибо всем за ответы